# IUPAC name of the tert-pentyl group

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the IUPAC name of *tert*-pentyl? I know that isopentyl is 2-methylpentane and neohexyl would be 2,2-methylhexane, but what about *tert*?

Answer (score 10):

The retained names “*tert*-pentyl”, “isopentyl”, and “neopentyl” were still included in the [1993 IUPAC recommendations](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_682.htm).

However, according to Subsection P-57.1.4 of the current version of [*Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013* (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001), these retained names are no longer recommended. The preferred prefix names are as follows:

- “*tert*-pentyl”: 2-methylbutan-2-yl
- “isopentyl”: 3-methylbutyl
- “neopentyl”: 2,2-dimethylpropyl

> **P-57.1.4** Retained prefixes no longer recommended
>
> The retained names phenethyl (2-phenylethyl) for $\ce{C6H5-CH2-CH2-{}}$; benzhydryl (diphenylmethyl), for $\ce{(C6H5)2CH-{}}$; isobutyl (2-methylbutyl) for $\ce{(CH3)2CH-CH2-{}}$; *sec*-butyl (butan-2-yl, 1-methylpropyl) for $\ce{CH3-CH2-CH(CH3)-{}}$; isopentyl (3-methylbutyl) for $\ce{(CH3)2CH-CH2-CH2-{}}$; *tert*-pentyl (2-methylbutan-2-yl, 1,1-dimethylpropyl) for $\ce{CH3-CH2-C(CH3)2-{}}$; and neopentyl (2,2-dimethylpropyl) for $\ce{(CH3)3C-CH2-{}}$; are no longer recommended; the first name in parentheses is the preferred prefix name.

Answer (score 5):

There is a really nifty chart for this on the [pentyl group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentyl_group) page of Wikipedia:

> $$ \small
> \begin{array}{lcc}
> \hline
> \text{Name} & \text{Structure} & \text{IUPAC status} & \text{IUPAC recommendation} \\
> \hline
> n\text{-pentyl} & \ce{-(CH2)4CH3}\ & \text{} & \text{pentyl} \\
> tert\text{-pentyl} & \ce{-C(CH3)2CH2CH3} & \text{Allowed} & \text{1,1-dimethylpropyl} \\
> \text{neopentyl} & \ce{-CH2C(CH3)3} & \text{Allowed} & \text{2,2-dimethylpropyl} \\
> \text{isopentyl} & \ce{-CH2CH2CH(CH3)2} & \text{Allowed} & \text{3-methylbutyl} \\
> sec\text{-pentyl} & \ce{-CH(CH3)CH2CH2CH3} & & \text{1-methylbutyl, pentan-2-yl} \\
> 3\text{-pentyl} & \ce{-CH(C2CH3)2} & & \text{1-ethylpropyl, pentan-3-yl} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

Comment: What would tert-Pentyl look like using a [Skeletal Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_formula) ?

Comment: @jimpix [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL3jt.png).

Comment: Last one in chart is wrong. The right formula is -CH(CH2CH3)2.

Comment: That is now corrected.